# Would AWS Step Functions map state be the best option for processing 10 million line CSV?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a workflow which could potentially require thousands or millions of Lambda invocations and am trying to understand if Step Functions map state will allow for the number of executions I need.

I'm creating a service that will be triggered by a CSV file uploaded to an S3 bucket. The CSV file will have many millions of event registrations that need to be processed (flow of different Lambdas) and have an output of a summary of successes, failures, etc. Looking at the different services I think Step Functions would work to orchestrate the flow. The map state allows for a dynamic number of sub-workflows but I have not found what that maximum number might be. I can batch my executions to limit the workflows if the number can be in the thousands. If not, I am considering some way to utilize SQS or trying to understand if AWS Batch is a valid option, too.

Would the map state of Step Functions work well for such a flow with a dynamic number of executions or would another service be the better option for my task?

Comment: Some clarifying questions: How long in total will it take to process all lines in such a file? Why do you think that AWS Lambda is an appropriate method for processing the file? Have you considered any other methods of processing the file?

Comment: At this time I am not entirely sure how long to process the whole file but each individual item in the file will take about 200 milliseconds. Thinking fan-out approach for multiple Lambda instances to execute this concurrently. Currently thinking Lambda as each line in the file will need to be converted to JSON, parsed, and then passed as a request to a particular API endpoint and have the response captured for final reporting of the whole process. But there are other resources and didn't see any that seemed to fit the bill better.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using Step Functions for this use case. `Map` state requires `ItemsPath` parameter which points to array of items in the `Data` (JSON that is passed from one state to another). This JSON is limited in size to 32K characters (effectively probably around 32KiB, I haven't been digging into details of encoding handling by Step Functions).
So this effectively rules out `Map` in Step Functions because you will simply hit the service limit with this amount of data.

In this use case I think it would be better to use SQS and Lambda. Uploading file to S3 would trigger Lambda which would trigger AWS Batch job which in turn would download CSV file and send messages for each row to one or more SQS queues (if you want different Lambda for different row types). Lambda has native integration with SQS, so you could use that.

Keep in mind that SQS might duplicate message so your Lambda should work correctly even if the same row is processed multiple times (Lambda should be idempotent). Basically any element of your system should be idempotent if you want to have reliable, distributed system.

Another solution (if you insist on using Step Functions) would be to start new Execution for each row in the CSV file, however, I think you would hit the service limits quickly and it would be costly.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, Step Functions now supports **Distributed mode** for Map states, enabling high-concurrency processing of JSON and CSV files from S3. The previous answer from 2019 is out of date.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-distributed.html